# White space issue when positioning a div relatively

Tags: html, css, sass

So I'm trying to go with this look, for example:

[image]

My code looks like this:

```
<div class="blog-posts">
  <article class="blog-post">
    <div class="featured-image">
      <a href="#"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/800x500"></a>
    </div>
    <div class="excerpt">
      <h1>Test Post 1</h1>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer tristique viverra leo, sed viverra nulla. Phasellus sollicitudin arcu odio, at ultricies orci consequat eget.</p>
    </div>
  </article>
  <article class="blog-post">
    <div class="featured-image">
      <a href="#"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/800x1000"></a>
    </div>
    <div class="excerpt">
      <h1>Test Post 1</h1>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer tristique viverra leo, sed viverra nulla. Phasellus sollicitudin arcu odio, at ultricies orci consequat eget.</p>
    </div>
  </article>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/tenold/5ondm4f3/3/

The issue I'm having is after moving the excerpt up into the image relatively, obviously there is white space left over at the bottom. How do I make it so there is no white space like in the example photo above?

Things to consider: the images could be any height. The excerpt text could be any length.

What is the best way to do this with CSS? I can't seem to figure it out. I can't seem to figure out a way to do it with absolute positioning because the heights of the images and text is variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using `position:relative` and `top` property the initial space taken by the `div` remain as it is and is not filled by other content even if the moved from its initial position. Like you can read [here](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp):

> Setting the top, right, bottom, and left properties of a
>   relatively-positioned element will cause it to be adjusted away from
>   its normal position. **Other content will not be adjusted to fit into**
>   **any gap left by the element**.

So I simply advise you to use negative value with `margin-top` instead. Don't forget to adjust the `z-index` to be sure the content remain on the the top of the image:

```css
.blog-posts {
  max-width: 800px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.blog-post {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #efefef;
  padding-bottom: 50px;
  margin-bottom: 50px;
}

.featured-image img {
  display: block;
}

.excerpt {
  max-width: 60%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background: white;
  padding: 50px;
  margin-top: -50px;
  position:relative;
  z-index:2;
  border: 1px solid #eee;
}

h1 {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  line-height: normal;
}

p {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  line-height: 200%;
}
```

```html
<div class="blog-posts">
  <article class="blog-post">
    <div class="featured-image">
      <a href="#"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/700x200"></a>
    </div>
    <div class="excerpt">
      <h1>Test Post 1</h1>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer tristique viverra leo, sed viverra nulla. Phasellus sollicitudin arcu odio, at ultricies orci consequat eget.</p>
    </div>
  </article>
  <article class="blog-post">
    <div class="featured-image">
      <a href="#"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/700x200"></a>
    </div>
    <div class="excerpt">
      <h1>Test Post 1</h1>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer tristique viverra leo, sed viverra nulla. Phasellus sollicitudin arcu odio, at ultricies orci consequat eget.</p>
    </div>
  </article>
  <article class="blog-post">
    <div class="featured-image">
      <a href="#"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/700x200"></a>
    </div>
    <div class="excerpt">
      <h1>Test Post 1</h1>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer tristique viverra leo, sed viverra nulla. Phasellus sollicitudin arcu odio, at ultricies orci consequat eget.</p>
    </div>
  </article>
</div>
```

Comment: Wow, not sure why I didn't think to use negative margin-top. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Replace `top` with `margin-top`, and add `z-index: 1` got get the element over the image on the z-axis ... done.

Relative positioning moves an element in regard to its static position, but leaves the original space the element would have occupied reserved; it still influences other element positions as if it was still in that original, static position. A negative margin-top however "drags" the whole element up, so that all following content in the flow will move up accordingly.

```
.excerpt {
  max-width:60%;
  margin:0 auto;
  background:white;
  padding:50px;
  position: relative;
  /*top:-50px;*/
  margin-top:-50px;
  z-index: 1;
```

https://jsfiddle.net/5ondm4f3/4/